# How can I parse a json response saved in a text file

Tags: java, json, yahoo-api

I have been looking at a tutorial on parsing json response using Java. the tutorial http://www.javabeat.net/2012/04/parsing-json-using-java-and-gson-library/ that says:

> Reading the JSON document using JsonReader, assuming the document is
>   present in the file systems:

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(this.jsonSource)));
```

I don't understand why we use this and what does it mean by jsonSource. My json response is saved in a text file. How can I deal with it ? should I put the text file path or what ? Can any body clarify to me how to parse a json response, in particular, Yahoo BOSS, in order to extract the search results links. For now, I was able to save the response in a text file. It is as (this response for the key word Yahoo):

```
    {"bossresponse":{"responsecode":"200","web":{"start":"0","count":"42","totalresults":"89200000","results":
[
{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/www.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/www.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"www.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!","abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/mail.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/mail.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"mail.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"Sign in to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!","abstract":"Your World. Your Way. <b>Yahoo<\/b>! makes it easy to enjoy what matters most in your world. Best in class <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mail, breaking local, national and global news, finance ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/groups.yahoo.com\/?ch=web&pub=fp-us&t=fp&sec=link&slk=defaultrough","url":"http:\/\/groups.yahoo.com\/?ch=web&pub=fp-us&t=fp&sec=link&slk=defaultrough","dispurl":"groups.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?ch=web&amp;pub=fp-us&amp;t=fp&amp;sec=link&amp;slk=...","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Groups - Join or create groups, clubs, forums ...","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Groups offers free mailing lists, photo &amp; file sharing, group calendars and more. Discuss hot topics, share interests, join online communities."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/homes.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/homes.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"homes.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Homes - Home for Sale and Rent, Makeovers, Design and ...","abstract":"Some <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Homes information is provided by our trusted partners. However, <b>Yahoo<\/b>! does not guarantee the accuracy or completeness of any third party content."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Yahoo","url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Yahoo","dispurl":"en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/<b>Yahoo<\/b>","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Inc. (NASDAQ: YHOO) is an American multinational internet corporation headquartered in Sunnyvale, California, United States. The company is best known for its ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/taxes.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/taxes.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"taxes.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance - Personal Finance | Taxes","abstract":"Taxes - Read latest articles and guides, try our comprehensive calculators, tools, and get advice at <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance"},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"omg.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"omg! Celebrity gossip, news photos, babies, couples, hotties ...","abstract":"The latest celebrity gossip from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg! Get the latest news and gossip on the Hollywood celebrities with videos and photos."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/uk.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/uk.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"uk.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! UK","abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/smallbusiness.yahoo.com\/?s_fptrough=ysb_acq_smallbiz_20081001","url":"http:\/\/smallbusiness.yahoo.com\/?s_fptrough=ysb_acq_smallbiz_20081001","dispurl":"smallbusiness.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?s_fptrough=ysb_acq_smallbiz...","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Small Business: Web Hosting, Domain Registration, E ...","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Small Business provides reliable web hosting for your website, domain name registration, web site design templates, e-commerce solutions for your ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/cricket.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/cricket.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"cricket.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Cricket - Live Cricket Score | Cricket News | Cricket ...","abstract":"Check out live cricket scores, cricket news headlines, cricket schedules &amp; results and more from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Cricket Includes ICC World Cricket League Championship 2012 ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/messenger.yahoo.com\/?i=1","url":"http:\/\/messenger.yahoo.com\/?i=1","dispurl":"messenger.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?i=1","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat, Instant message, SMS, Video Call, PC ...","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat with friends for free and enjoy stealth settings, video calls, PC calls, file sharing, photo sharing, SMS, emoticons, &amp; more."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/uk.my.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/uk.my.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"uk.my.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"My <b>Yahoo<\/b>! - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! UK","abstract":"My <b>Yahoo<\/b>! is a customisable web page from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! UK. Personalise your page by adding news, stock quotes, weather, email, social updates and much more."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/search.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/search.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"search.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Search - Web Search","abstract":"Learn about the new <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Axis. A better way to search. Way better. Get it Now! &gt;&gt;"},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"news.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! News - Latest News &amp; Headlines","abstract":"The latest news and headlines from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! News. Get breaking news stories and in-depth coverage with videos and photos."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/au.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/au.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"au.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!7","abstract":"The <b>Yahoo<\/b>! for Australia offering local &amp; global search, free email, instant messaging, news, sport, travel, shopping, movies &amp; music."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/ca.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/ca.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"ca.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Canada","abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Canada, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/everything.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/everything.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"everything.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! International ... © 2012 <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Inc. All rights reserved"},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/football.fantasysports.yahoo.com\/?ovchn=YAH&ovcpn=Front+Page&ovcrn=Front+page+P+Link+Nav+button&ovrfd=YAH&ovtac=AD","url":"http:\/\/football.fantasysports.yahoo.com\/?ovchn=YAH&ovcpn=Front+Page&ovcrn=Front+page+P+Link+Nav+button&ovrfd=YAH&ovtac=AD","dispurl":"football.fantasysports.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/?ovchn=YAH&amp;ovcpn=Front...","title":"It's Game Time! - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Sports Fantasy Football","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Fantasy Football. Create or join a NFL league and manage your team with FREE live scoring, stats, scouting reports, news, and expert advice."},


{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/music.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/music.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"music.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Music - Exclusive New Music and Music Videos","abstract":"Find all the new music and exclusive video performances on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Music. Get the latest news in our exclusive music blogs, listen to our online music radio and catch ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/uk.messenger.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/uk.messenger.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"uk.messenger.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat, Instant message, Video Call, PC Calls","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Messenger - Chat with friends for free and enjoy stealth settings, video calls, PC calls, file sharing, photo sharing, emoticons, &amp; more."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/in.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/in.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"in.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! India","abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/companion.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/companion.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"companion.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Toolbar - Stay in touch with your world.","abstract":"Toolbar for <b>Yahoo<\/b>! search, alerts for <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mail and an option to save bookmarks online."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/photos\/","url":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/photos\/","dispurl":"movies.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/photos","title":"Movie Pictures | Movie Posters - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies","abstract":"View movie pictures and stills from the latest releases on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies. Find movie posters, red carpet photos and pictures from upcoming movies."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/local.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"local.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"Redmond City Pages on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Local. Find Businesses, Services ...","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Local has Redmond business reviews, top rated services, and events near Redmond, WA. Use interactive maps, driving directions reviews and ratings to find the ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/yahooligans.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/yahooligans.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"<b>yahoo<\/b>ligans.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"Kids Games, Kids Movies, Kids Music, and More - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Kids","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b> Kids! is the ultimate web guide for kids! Features fun and educational resources for kids with games, animals, music, jokes, movies, news, astrology, TV ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/m.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/m.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"m.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mobile","abstract":"Welcome to <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mobile. Stay up to date on the go with business, sports, and entertainment news."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/tv.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/tv.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"tv.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! TV","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! TV is your guide to everything about TV online, from TV show listings and episode guides, to the latest TV show photos, clips, news, recaps, cast &amp; credits ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/shopping.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/shopping.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"shopping.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Shopping - Online Shopping with great products, prices ...","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Shopping is the best place to read user reviews, explore great products and buy online."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/dir.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/dir.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"dir.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Directory","abstract":"Help us improve the <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Directory - Share your ideas"},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/overview.mail.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/overview.mail.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"overview.mail.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Mail","abstract":"Your favorite email is now: FASTER: 2x faster. How great is that? So great. SAFER: Even better spam protection. Yes! EASIER: Clean, simple design that makes email a ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/travel.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/travel.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"travel.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Travel - Cheap flights, hotels, travel guides &amp; car rental","abstract":"Find cheap flights, hotels and car rentals with <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Travel. Plan your trip with travel guides, personalized recommendations, articles, deals and more."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/news\/","url":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/news\/","dispurl":"omg.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/news","title":"Celebrity News | Celebrity Gossip - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg!","abstract":"Get the latest celebrity news from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg! Find the latest news about the Hollywood celebrities with videos and photos"},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/games.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/games.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"games.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Games - Play Free Online Games | Download Games","abstract":"Play the latest online games on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Games. Play and download single and multiplayer games from a wide selection of arcade, board and puzzle games."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/photos\/","url":"http:\/\/omg.yahoo.com\/photos\/","dispurl":"omg.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/photos","title":"Celebrity Photos | Pictures of Celebrities - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg!","abstract":"View the latest celebrity photos on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! omg! Get the latest red carpet pictures and photos from Hollywood."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/q?s=","url":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/q?s=","dispurl":"finance.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/q?s=","title":"Quotes &amp;amp; Info- <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance","abstract":"View the basic stock chart on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance. Change the date range, chart type and compare against other companies."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/movies.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"movies.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies - Upcoming Movies, Trailers and Showtimes","abstract":"View the latest trailers and movie reviews on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Movies. Find everything about movies online, from upcoming releases, movie ratings, trailers and movie news"},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/screen.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/screen.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"screen.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"Watch videos online - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Screen","abstract":"Watch videos online for free on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Screen. Find sports, kids and funny videos including the latest news video clips."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/privacy.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/privacy.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"privacy.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Privacy Policy","abstract":"WHAT THIS PRIVACY POLICY COVERS <b>Yahoo<\/b>! takes your privacy seriously. Please read the following to learn more about our privacy policy. The federal ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/us\/","url":"http:\/\/news.yahoo.com\/us\/","dispurl":"news.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com\/us","title":"U.S. News Headlines - <b>Yahoo<\/b>! News","abstract":"Get the latest U.S. news headlines from <b>Yahoo<\/b>! News. Find breaking U.S. news, including analysis and opinion on top U.S. stories."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/fantasysports.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/fantasysports.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"fantasysports.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"Fantasy on <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Sports - News, Scores, Standings, Rumors ...","abstract":"Comprehensive Fantasy news, scores, standings, fantasy games, rumors, and more"},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/finance.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"finance.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance - Business Finance, Stock Market, Quotes, News","abstract":"At <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Finance, you get free stock quotes, up to date news, portfolio management resources, international market data, message boards, and mortgage ..."},

{"date": "","clickurl":"http:\/\/world.yahoo.com\/","url":"http:\/\/world.yahoo.com\/","dispurl":"world.<b>yahoo<\/b>.com","title":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>!: <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Everywhere","abstract":"<b>Yahoo<\/b>! USA (en Español) ... © 2012 <b>Yahoo<\/b>! Inc. All rights reserved"}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.jsonSource` is simply a variable that contains the file (or the name of the file) to read. See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) to check what the FileInputStream constructors take as argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just save the data to a string without JsonReader then parse the string to JSON.